# Visual Studio - EnvDTE.DTE.Solution.Open does not add solution/project to recent list

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte

After opening a solution programmatically with EnvDTE.DTE.Solution.Open there is no entry in VS at File->Recent Projects and Solutions or at the StartPage under "Recent".

Is possible to add the opened solution programmatically to the recent list?

Comment: I don't see a point to keep this question here, when You have found answer at other question on SO and answered it yourself there. Clearly a duplicate and should be closed/deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jason Malinowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/972216/jason-malinowski) gave the right answer in this post [open solution & add to MRU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573115/how-can-you-make-the-file-get-added-to-the-recent-projects-mru-list-when-program).

Get the service with `(IVsSolution)ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsSolution))` and use `OpenSolutionFile`.